# Proving Aleph Number Equations

Tags: set-theory

I am very stuck on how to prove the opposite of what I was given.

Ok so I have two equations that involve Aleph numbers

$\aleph_{1}^{\aleph_{0}} = 2^{\aleph_{0}}$

and

$\aleph_{0}^{\aleph_{1}} = 2^{\aleph_{1}}$

The first one seems easy because by the Continuum Hypothesis

$2^{\aleph_{0}} = \aleph_{1}$

so I just substituted

$\aleph_{1}^{\aleph_{0}} \leq  (2^{\aleph_{0}} )^{\aleph_{0}} = 2^{\aleph_{0} \cdot \aleph_{0}} =  2^{\aleph_{0}}$

But for

$\aleph_{0}^{\aleph_{1}} = 2^{\aleph_{1}}$

I am not sure... like I could try and use the Continuum Hypothesis again such that

$2^{\aleph_{0}} = \aleph_{1}$

becomes $\aleph_{0}^{2^{\aleph_{0}}}$ but this is so messy and backwards.

How can I prove that 
$\aleph_{0}^{\aleph_{1}} = 2^{\aleph_{1}}$
 is valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CH is a red herring**. *And a proof using it isn't an outright proof, so you should resist it regardless.*

EDIT: Per the comments below, the key point here is that *basic cardinal arithmetic is boring*: for all infinite $\kappa,\lambda$ we have $$\kappa+\lambda=\kappa\cdot\lambda=\max\{\kappa,\lambda\},$$ and this (or rather, the multiplication part) is the rule which lets us solve the problems above. It's only when we come to exponentiation that interesting things happen.

---

Your proof of $(1)$ doesn't actually use CH! Regardless of whether CH is true, we know $2^{\aleph_0}\ge\aleph_1$. So the calculation $$(\aleph_1)^{\aleph_0}\le(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0\cdot\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$$ doesn't need CH. The converse $2^{\aleph_0}\le(\aleph_1)^{\aleph_0}$ is trivial, and so you're done.

---

For $(2)$, the same basic idea is going to work. This time, use the fact that $2^{\aleph_0}\ge\aleph_0$. This gives us $$(\aleph_0)^{\aleph_1}\le (2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_1}.$$ Do you see how to proceed to get $(\aleph_0)^{\aleph_1}\le 2^{\aleph_1}$ (the converse being trivial as before)?

Comment: Wait a sec...so I do not have to use the Continuum Hypothesis on this? This is what I am thinking for the second one which is $(\aleph_{0})^{\aleph_{1}} \leq (2^{\aleph_{0}})^{\aleph_{1}} =  2^{\aleph_{0} \cdot \aleph_{1}} = 2^{\aleph_{1}}$ ???

Comment: @usukidoll Yup, that's right. CH isn't relevant to any of this - everything there (and in $(1)$) is just true, full stop, regardless of whether CH holds.

Comment: dahhh I'm trying to get my latex to work on the other one

Comment: Ok now that I got my latex fixed, how does  $\aleph_{0} \cdot \aleph_{1}$ imply $\aleph_{1}$???? That is where I am getting lost

Comment: @usukidoll *(I think "imply" should be "equal" in your previous comment?)* When $\kappa,\lambda$ are infinite cardinals we have $$\kappa+\lambda=\kappa\cdot\lambda=\max\{\kappa,\lambda\}.$$ This is a basic fact of cardinal arithmetic (and has nothing to do with CH).

Comment: like ohh by cardinal addition if $\aleph_{0} + \aleph_{1} = \aleph_{0+1} = \aleph_{1}$ ?

Comment: @usukidoll You can't add subscripts like that! E.g. $\aleph_1+\aleph_1=\aleph_1$, not $\aleph_2$. The rule is exactly what I've written above. (These arithmetic facts are things you should be comfortable with *before* tackling problems around exponentiation.)

Comment: oh ok so we are taking the max of those two subscripts  max $\{0,1 \}$ and the max is one so $\aleph_{1}$

Comment: @usukidoll Yes, if you want to work with subscripts we have $$\aleph_\alpha+\aleph_\beta=\aleph_\alpha \cdot\aleph_\beta=\aleph_{\max\{\alpha,\beta\}}.$$ (And I strongly recommend mastering the proof of this before continuing with problems about cardinal exponentaition.)