# Prove this inequality: $100 * \aleph_1 * \aleph_0^{\aleph_1} <(2*\aleph_1)^{\aleph_0}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I looked at this thread [Proving Aleph Number Equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3373677/proving-aleph-number-equations) but didn't understand.

So:

$$100 * \aleph_1 * \aleph_0^{\aleph_1} <(2*\aleph_1)^{\aleph_0}$$

$$\aleph_1 * \aleph_0^{\aleph_1} < 2^{\aleph_0} * \aleph_1^{\aleph_0}$$

$$\aleph_1 * \aleph_0^{\aleph_1} < \aleph_1 * \aleph_1$$

$$\aleph_1 * \aleph_0^{\aleph_1} < \aleph_1$$

and this is where we get stuck.

I tried multiplying both sides by $2^{\aleph_1}$ and that gets me equality?

Wolfram Alpha says that $\aleph_0^{\aleph_1}=2^{\aleph_1}$ but the thread linked at the top proves that wrong?

Is my professor wrong? Am I wrong? Was Cantor too high for this?

Plz help :(

Comment: It looks like you're assuming CH in the third line ...

Comment: Thanks for the edit, new around here!

Comment: MathJax hint:  You can use underline to get subscripts, so \aleph_0 will give $\aleph_0$.  If the subscript is more than one character, enclose it in braces.

Answer (score 2):

The statement you're trying to prove is false - in fact, the inequality should essentially be the other way around: it's easy to show$^1$ $$(\aleph_0)^{\aleph_1}\ge(\aleph_1)^{\aleph_0},$$ and the additional "noise" - multiplying the left hand side by $100\aleph_1$ and replacing the $\aleph_1$ in the right hand side by $2\aleph_1$ - doesn't change anything. *Remember that infinite cardinal multiplication is boring ...*

Meanwhile, the statement $(\aleph_0)^{\aleph_1}=2^{\aleph_1}$ is **true**; I'm not sure why you think the linked thread contradicts that. (Maybe you misread a "$\le$" as a "$<$"?)

---

$^1$Per Cantor we have $\aleph_1\le 2^{\aleph_0}$. This means that $(\aleph_1)^{\aleph_0}\le (2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}$. Now we apply a couple basic facts about cardinal arithmetic which give $$(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0\cdot\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0},$$ so putting this all together we get $$(\aleph_1)^{\aleph_0}\le 2^{\aleph_0}.$$ The other direction is immediate, so in fact we get $$(\aleph_1)^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}.$$ But $(\aleph_0)^{\aleph_1}$ is trivially at least as big as $2^{\aleph_0}$ since $\aleph_0>2$ and $\aleph_1>\aleph_0$, so we can conclude $$(\aleph_0)^{\aleph_1}\ge(\aleph_1)^{\aleph_0}$$ as claimed above.

Interestingly, **it is consistent with the ZFC axioms** that $(\aleph_0)^{\aleph_1}=(\aleph_1)^{\aleph_0}$, since it is consistent with ZFC that $2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_1}$. Of course, *proving* this consistency is extremely hard ...

Comment: I've emailed my professor, I'm going to review this tomorrow as I've been sitting on this problem for a few hours and I'm beat. Your help is most appreciated, thank you very much :)

P.S I have no idea what the ZFC Axioms are, will look into that later haha